# Proof of Char(R)

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose we have a ring $R$ such that $char(R)$=$k$ with $k>0$.

(a) Let $p=mk$, where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $px=0_R$for all $x\in R$. [Remember that $p$ is an integer and $x$ is an element of the ring.]

: I think, since $k$ is $Char(R)$, it is true that $kx=0_R$ for all $x\in R$. Then assume $p=mk$, want to show $px=0_R$, in other words, show $mkx=0
_R$(??) 
Then, we know $kx=0_R$, so $m\cdot 0_R=0_R$  isn't it?

(b) Suppose that $px=0_R$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $p=mk$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ [Use the Division Algorithm]

: I need some guidelines here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're ok about the first question. For b), divide $p$ by $k$ obtaining $p=kq+r$ where $0\leq r<k$. Then $px=0$ implies $(kq+r)x = kqx +rx= rx=0$. By the definition of the characteristic being $k$ there can be no nonzero integer $r<k$ satisfying $rx=0$ for every x\in R, therefore $r$ must be zero, so $p=qk$.

**Note:** You should be more careful with your notations. Further, since the char. is zero or a prime (as noted in the comments, assuming $R$ is an integral domain), people usually denote the char. of a ring as $p$.

Comment: Are we assuming $R$ is a domain? Otherwise char(R) does not have to be zero or a prime.

Comment: We assume $char(R)=k$, $k>0$ at the beginning. How we got $kqx+rx=rx$?

Comment: @Wes Note that $xk=0$.

Comment: @ViniciusM. Thanks, but I am still confused with $rx=0$. Could you explain more about that?

Comment: @Wes, by hypothesis $px = 0$, by euclidean division we found out that $p = kq+r$, $x(kq+r) = 0$, thus $xkq + xr = 0$, since $xkq=0$ then $xr = 0$. What's the step you didn't understand?

Comment: I thought I wasn't allowed to assume $x(kq+r)=0$ at the first place. I thought I solve $kqx+rx$ to get $0$. So, I thought $kqx=kxq=0_Rq=0_R$ that means we have $0_R+rx=rx$. But I wan't sure what to do with $rx$ to get $rx=0$.

Comment: You are not assuming it, it's given to you that $xp=0$, now $p=kq+r$, so...

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. But if it is given, then I don't know why need to expand $(kq+r)x$.We could just conclude that$(kq+r)x=0$..... But now while writing this comment, I think I got it..! Thank you for your help! :)